# For dynamic reactive forms, is there a reason to register controls that don't hold value or state?

Tags: angular

A general question . . . Based on button clicks, I'm dynamically adding components to a form. The components are composed of multiple pairs of inputs and labels, and also include additional buttons. The labels and buttons don't hold state or value, so prima facie I don't see a need to register these. But I'd like to make sure that there isn't a scenario that I'm overlooking in which I could get into trouble if I don't register the labels and buttons.

To put it another way, is it safe to forego the following:

```
this.formControls[key]=new FormControl('', validators);    
this.form.addControl("myName", this.formControls[key]);
```

for the labels and buttons?
(Note: within the component, I create and destroy all the elements together).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I did not get your point but why not use FormArray ?

Comment: Two things: If formsControl is a FormGroup use this.formControl.AddControl(...) see https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl. The second it that I think that if you needn't the value of label, you are correct: it's not necesary the label was a control. You generally use the Form to send values to an API, (eventually to a dbs to update or insert). Your API don't need the value of the "label" so Why must be necesary send it?